# Distribution failed with errors itunes connect

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, itunes-store, application-loader

I am facing an issue while uploading a new version on the apple store. I am using `Xcode Organizer` to push a new version. When I have an archive, its successful done, however, I am not able to upload it successfully. I have chosen Distribute app option when archive did but in middle of uploading it, stops and error occurred.

Here is the image which is showing what exactly happens.

[image]

I have tried to remove and add again apple id and password as I am using the auto sign method so I thought might be some issue occurred because of it. But not able to get any success.

Even I have used `Application Loader` for uploading but the same issue I faced. Here is the image for application loader.

[image]

If anyone aware of it kindly help me to come out from this weird issue.

Comment: 1. Please check your net connectivity.
2. Try to upload with a different network.

Comment: @Aditya Not working. I have tried with other network which has static IP. But still not able to upload it. :(

Comment: Did you try with your mobile network?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have issue with your machine or `Xcode`. You should try on another machine will fix your issue. Sometimes it's happening due to some network proxies or machine not configured properly.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to upload using Application Loader. At first it seemed like it's stuck as well, but after about 10 minutes it started uploading.

Comment: I am facing same issue with application loader. Same 4 error. Please see my question i have edited.